# Python Django urls.py, views.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Есть urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    re_path('(?P<project_name>\D+)/', views.products),
]
```

Вот products

```
def products(request, project_name):
    now_name = str(project_name).lower
    if product_name == 'project':
        return HttpResponse('project страница проекта. {0}'.format(now_name))
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Изначально: {0}. Стало: {1}'.format(project_name, now_name))
```

Хочу сделать чтобы now_name был строчным product_name для сравнения, но вместо этого строка становится пустой. Т.е. в итоге получается now_name - пустая строка, а project_name - то что ввел пользователь. Как правильно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Забыл написать скобки после .lower

Т.е. правильно .lower()